# Is it possible to shoot through squad shields?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

If I deploy a Squad Shield around a few of my teammates and I, is it possible for enemies to shoot through the shield with heavy weapons such as the AT-ST's canon, the AT-AT's canons, turrets, or air vehicles?

I have a feeling this is possible because I think it happened to me. I was standing inside a Squad Shield and an AT-ST appeared to shoot through it.

Comment: I have no evidence of it, but I believe I've also seen AT-AT's shoot through those shields.

Comment: I believe the cycler rifle at least can do it. I remember reading in it's description that it shoots through shields

Comment: All physical-damage weapons can pierce the shield, as well as the shield can break if it is attacked enough. The physical weapons I'm aware of in the game are the cycler rifle, implosion grenade, and thermal detonator.

Comment: Heavy weapons have a large impact radius - I suspect the shot hits the shield and the radius kills everything inside anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-traditional weapons can go through the squad shield, like rockets, missiles, cycler rifle shots, thermal detonators, etc. If it is considered a "physical" shot (like it's a bullet instead of a laser) it can go through the shield.

Vehicle main weapons are blocked by the shield but can hit the ground near the shield and cause area-of-effect damage through the shield. The AT-ST, as an example, doesn't need a direct hit to kill someone. If it hits the ground near you, its' explosive range will still kill you.

Comment: Can confirm this, the hardest part of surviving in this game is trying to figure out which lasers have that AOE effect when they hit.

Comment: The charge up lasers (special ability) of heroes can also shoot through shields. Though the hero regular blaster fire is still blocked as usual.